# How can we know if a VM is HyperV instance using bash?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, hyper-v

I know we can check Vendor details using following command

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/sys_vendor
```

But in case of Azure VM and HyperV VM, it's same - Microsoft Corporation.

I need a proper/unique way to check if the VM is on HyperV.

Comment: Did you check the available hardware (in the vm via drivers?) There may be difference in the shown devices. I.e. network card, graphics card may show different virtual drivers.

Comment: There is tool which is called `virt-what`. You can easily find deb or rpm package regarding your distro.

Comment: @TomTom, I checked, Almost everything is same. Some dynamic configurations are different but that is not a good to differentiate as they can be changed.

Comment: @LittleSmurfie, Thanks But I don't need to find out the packages. Also, I am not allowed to install anything on these VMs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tell the hypervisor type in a Linux guest, use the `virt-what` script. If using Ansible, the `ansible_facts['virtualization_type']` fact is similar, and also works on non-Linux hosts.

Hypervisor type does not tell you the hosting provider. To do that in guest, access any available [instance metadata service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service). Each implements this differently, use that to tell them apart. For example, Azure's response will have a `compute` dict with a `azEnvironment` key, indicating which Azure cloud.